# Custom CRS for artwork in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am analyzing a height map of a painting. The heightmap is 18cm x 18cm, and the depth of the paint is 0.5mm.

Can someone tell me what WKT and Parameter codes I might be able to use in QGIS?

Comment: You can literally use **any** EPSG code,  because it's not going to tie into any real world place.

Comment: Okay, but then how do I set the custom size of the map, and its height?

Comment: Not necessary. They're arbitrary units anyway.

Comment: And Thank you, Vince!

Comment: @Vince is there any way to set the scale so the units become less arbitrary? Right now my heightmap is ranging from 16k to 55k units. I'd like to make it look more like 0 to 10.

Comment: We have a One question per Question policy here. Vertical exaggeration is a common requirement (in the other direction), but you seem to have a number of options, since you control data capture and presentation..

Comment: @Vince Thank you again!

Comment: If you want to take measurements, you better *not* use *any* CRS or you might end up with misinterpretation of geographic coordinates, an ellipsoid and what not. Just use the "invalid projection" that QGIS will use when you import your image and set your project to "No CRS (or unknown/non-Earth projection)". Then things should be cartesian or lead to errors instead of wrong results.

Comment: This is a sufficiently "off-label" use of GIS that sharing and distribution of useless data doesn't seem a major concern.

Comment: If you don't have consideration for novice users on this site conducting wrong analyses and calculating false metrics in their workflows then please so not suggest dangerous and misleading approaches to them.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to take measurements or do anything based on the units, you better *not* use *any* CRS or you might end up with misinterpretation of geographic coordinates, an ellipsoid and whatnot.

Just use the "invalid projection" that QGIS will use when you import your image and set your project to "No CRS (or unknown/non-Earth projection)". Then things should be considered Cartesian by QGIS' tools or at least lead to explicit errors instead of wrong results.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a projection, use an **engineering projection**. This is the type that has been used for a coordinate systems on ships, a construction site, or images.

```
ENGCRS["A construction site CRS",
  EDATUM["P1",ANCHOR["Peg in south corner"]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
      AXIS["site east",southWest,ORDER[1]],
      AXIS["site north",southEast,ORDER[2]],
      LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0],
   USAGE[SCOPE["Construction"],TIMEEXTENT["date/time t1","date/time t2"]]
]
```

> continuous (not discrete) CRS for an image.

```
ENGCRS["An analogue image CRS",
 EDATUM["Image reference point",
 ANCHOR["Top left corner of image = 0,0"]],
 CS[Cartesian,2],
  AXIS["Column (x)",columnPositive],
  AXIS["Row (y)",rowPositive],
  LENGTHUNIT["micrometre",1E-6]]
```

I pulled this from [Open Geospatial](http://www.opengis.net/doc/is/wkt-crs/2.0.6). A few searches didn't turn up any other source.

You would want to change several values as below. Check the open geospatial page for what options there are. I am guessing this is close to what you want/need and I could easily be wrong. You will need to test this to be sure it is what you expect and will probably need to adjust to suit your needs.

```
ENGCRS["An image CRS",
  DATUM["Image reference point", ANCHOR["Top left corner of image = 0,0"]],
    CS[Cartesian,3],
      AXIS["(X)",columnPositive,ORDER[1]],
      AXIS["(Y)",rowPositive,ORDER[2]],
      AXIS["(Z)",up,ORDER[3]],
      LENGTHUNIT["millimetre",0.001],
   USAGE[SCOPE["Painting Investigation"],]
]
```