# How to make the longitude decrease from south to north in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates

I want to make the value of the Y coordinate decrease as I go north on the map, and latitude should be the same (decreasing to the west and increasing to the east) in QGIS. I tried various coordinate systems, even those which are "south up", but it seems that no matter what coordinate system you use, Y coordinate will always increase as you move north. It should be done for whole project, not for single layer.

So basically I just want to invert Y axis, but I am new to QGIS, and I cant find out how to do this.

Comment: Hi Andrij Vlk, welcome to GIS SE. Great to have you here! Without having the context, this does not seem to make any sense. Maybe you can explain what you need this for? If what you're looking for does not exist, it could mean that there's a reason why it is so and there are better options. I have the impression this is a case of an XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Yeah, this just screams "XY Problem!"

Comment: @Babel I want to put on a map hundreds of locations from minecraft server where I play. In minecraft, when you go north, your second coordinate is decreasing. I understand that I can manually change the sign of coordinate, or use some kind of python command instead. But i also want to add terrain images there, so I think manual plus and minus sign changing is a waste of time when I can just flip the axis. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I may not understand your problem but could you georeference your images with tfw world files https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file and change the sign of the fourth parameter? BTW longitudes go from West to East.

Comment: Based upon "locations from minecraft server" I would say you need to create a custom projection. That is there are projections defined for paintings, ships, work sites etc.

Comment: Remember to update the question with the background information (and not just the comments). It will help future people who visit this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a engineering projection.

I posted an [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/456312/174139) to a question about [custom-crs-for-artwork](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/456182/custom-crs-for-artwork-in-qgis/456312). Which is a similar problem, different specifics.

Maybe a projection like the following would do for your problem. You will need to try and verify and probably change some of the values. Like, I did not look up where zero is for Minecraft.

```
ENGCRS["A Minecraft CRS for server ...",
  DATUM["Minecraft origin", ANCHOR["Top left corner of image = 0,0"]],
    CS[Cartesian,3],
      AXIS["(X)",columnPositive,ORDER[1]],
      AXIS["(Y)",rowNegative,ORDER[2]],
      AXIS["(Z)",up,ORDER[3]],
      LENGTHUNIT["meter",1],
   USAGE[SCOPE["Minecraft server ..."],]
]
```

Details of wkt projection defintions are from [opengis](http://www.opengis.net/doc/is/wkt-crs/2.0.6)